Is there a law against biohacking your pet?
Biohacking, particularly the self administration of genetic modification tools such as CRISPR, has become somewhat popular in recent years with advancements in genetic engineering technology.  While this technology is robustly regulated in the lab the only law I can find that limits personal use in any way is a 2019 California law requiring “the kit is not for self-administration” label for the relatively cheap DIY kits.
Are there any legal restrictions where applying such kits to oneself would be legal but doing so to ones pet would be illegal?

The animal can't consent to what amounts to kitchen sink genetic experimentation. I'm pretty sure there are animal abuse laws that would stretch to cover this.

@Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI I don't know of many animal abuse laws that care about whether an animal consented.

@bdb484 I mean in the same vein as animal abuse laws that would absolutely cover things like picking up experimental cosmetic surgery as a hobby and trying to trim your cat's ears. The operative term might be "duty of care", which I'm pretty sure extends to "Don't do this"

I think that's all pretty far off base.

uk
In the UK this is governed by the Veterinary Surgeons Act 1966 (which covers Scotland as well as England and Wales). A summary of the bits relevant to this question is at the Royal College of Veterinary Surgeons.
Briefly, a pet owner can only perform minor medical treatment. "Minor" isn't clearly defined, but the RCVS page suggests that a subcutaneous injection would be covered as long as a qualified vet said to do it. (Note: livestock on farms have a broader set of legal procedures, but that isn't relevant to pets).
However this would have to be a medical treatment. Again, that word isn't defined in the act, but it generally means medical care for illness or injury, or things like vaccinations to prevent injury. So it would depend a lot on why this was done, the likely side effects and so forth. I don't know of any case law, but I suspect the presumption would be against the administration of anything not prescribed by a vet.

My understanding is that owners administering steroids to pets is common in the UK, and I thought it was considered legal as it is for personal use.  It would seem similar to that in likely impact and evasiveness.

@User65535 It may be common, but that doesn't make it legal.

There are a number of provisions in the (England and Wales) Animal Welfare Act that could be applied.  They don't specifically mention "biohacking" or technology like CRISPR, but could be used after the fact (if, for example, the modifications caused suffering)
The general intent of the law is to prevent cruelty to "protected animals" (ie pets and domesticated animals).  The scope is quite wide.  A person causes an offence if he causes or allows an animal to suffer unnecessarily, and there are specific provisions against carrying out procedures that interfere with sensitive tissues or the bone structure of an animal, and the administration of drugs or poisons.
The intent was to make mutilation of animals (for cosmetic, sporting, fighting etc) an offence, but it would seem quite reasonable to extend this genetic modification, especially if the modification resulted in any pain or suffering for the animal.

Again in the UK, I believe that any form of experimentation on vertebrates needs a license.

@MarkMorganLloyd - Is it experimentation though if you already know what the expected outcome of the procedure is?

@ScottishTapWater most of the experiments have expected outcomes. The question is whether the outcomes were expected correctly. Drugs are developped to have some effect so the experiment tests this expectation to be true, false or indecisive.

California Penal Code §597(a) punishes anyone who “maliciously and intentionally maims, mutilates, tortures, or wounds a living animal”.
Whether a particular instance of “biohacking” constituted a violation of the code would be fact-specific.  You might claim that the biohacking was for the animal’s own good, or that it was legitimate scientific curiosity — but you would have to convince a jury.
There does not seem to be a law here that specifically says you have to be licensed to biohack an animal you own.
There are Federal laws (the Animal Welfare Act of 1966 for example), but the prosecution would not only have to prove you violated them, but you did so “in interstate commerce”.

The "interstate commerce" bit is likely trivial to prove. If just one ingredient or component of the injection (including the vial and syringe) has come from out of state then its interstate commerce.

@PaulJohnson — no, such a usage would entirely swallow Federalism.  The activity would have to have a genuine nexus with interstate commerce.

@MichaelLorton Using a kit which is available or made from parts available in multiple states or has competition with other kits which are available in multiple states would seem to be enough per Gonzales v Raich "In both cases, the regulation is squarely within Congress' commerce power because production of the commodity meant for home consumption...has a substantial effect on supply and demand in the national market for that commodity."  Granted this is distinguished by being use rather than production but SCOTUS usually chooses to expand the Commerce Clause.

Another argument could be that the creation of modified animals itself produces a good that could be sold, which would more squarely fall into Gonzales v Raich's opinion that even the personal production and use of a good can be regulated by the Federal government as affecting interstate commerce.  By the by "swallows Federalism" is a great description of SCOTUS' interpretation of the Commerce Clause.

@MichaelLorton Federalism is dead in practice, partly because the courts have been so absurdly broad in their interpretation of what constitutes "interstate commerce." The federal government basically ignores the concept that there is any limit on what they can impose on the states or the people, and with the Senate directly elected since the early 1900s, there's no mechanism for the states to actually assert any authority and act as a check on the federal bureaucracy.

@IllusiveBrian — Raich, like Wickard v. Filburn depended on the Federal government establish a “nationwide scheme” to regulate commerce (in cannabis and wheat respectively).  There is no nationwide scheme to regulate pets, biohacking, or pet biohacking.

@MichaelLorton: That's the whole point of the Interstate Commerce Clause; the federal government would be largely toothless otherwise.

@Vikki — even without the Commerce Clause (not the “Interstate” Commerce Clause, it also regulates trade with other nations, include Indian tribes), the Federal government can still collect taxes; pay debts and borrow money; coin money; establish post offices; protect patents and copyrights; establish lower courts; declare war; and raise and support an Army and Navy.  I kinda liked it that way.

Various jurisdictions have laws on the release of GMO in the wild. In EU directive 2001/18/EC, article 2 defines GMO for the purpose of the directive to exclude humans, while subsequent articles clarifiy that the scope goes beyond GM food. Doing what you describe in a home setting would presumably not meet the national safety and reporting criteria.

I think this is probably the most relevant answer.  I assume "release in the wild" is not actually required, it is the creation of the GMO in the first place that would be a crime?

@User65535, I'm not certain what one would be allowed to do in a proper lab with proper safeguards.

I don't think CRISPR counts as GMO unless it modifies the germ cells (which have specific defences against that). The issue with GMO is that the modifications are included in the descendants, which isn't generally the case with this kind of technology.
